# PHP on Apache + FastCGI with multiple file extensions

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008-r2, php5, fastcgi

Following the [php documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.apache2.php#install.windows.apache2.fastcgi), I've set up PHP to work with Apache2+FastCGI with the following configuration (in httpd.conf):

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
FcgidInitialEnv PHPRC "c:/php" 
AddHandler fcgid-script .php .html
FcgidWrapper "c:/php/php-cgi.exe" .php
FcgidWrapper "c:/php/php-cgi.exe" .html
```

I've tried the following as an alternative for the last three lines as well:

```
<Files ~ "\.html>" 
AddHandler fcgid-script .html
SetHandler fcgid-script
FcgidWrapper "c:/php/php-cgi.exe" .html
</Files>
```

However, only files that end with `.php` are being run as PHP scripts, and files with the `.html` extension are not.  There doesn't appear to be any other place in the config file that specifies the .php extension so I don't know why httpd is treating them differently.

Directly running `php-cgi.exe index.html` produces the expected output, so it would appear the problem lies in httpd not passing control to the cgi executable.

What's the right way to do this?

Specific version information:

- Apache HTTPD 2.2.22
- mod_fcgid-2.3.6-win32
- php-5.2.17-nts-Win32-VC6-x86
- Windows Server 2008 RC2

Answer (score 0):

I did a small test using:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script php fcg fcgi fpl html
FcgidWrapper "/usr/bin/php-cgi -d date.timezone=America/New_York" .html
FcgidWrapper "/usr/bin/php-cgi -d date.timezone=America/New_York" .php
```

and it was successful in using php to deliver .html files.  I would look through you're Apache config file and see if you have declared a handler for .html files beforehand or even after.